# ubuntu wont trust StarMade

Tags: software-installation

When I tried to install StarMade from http://star-made.org/download it told me The file '/home/gabriel/Downloads/StarMade-Starter (1).jar' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable

any answers for me???

Comment: @karel how is this a duplicate of a question about shell script execution? it is about a java file.

Comment: From the answer by Saurav Kumar: `cd containing-folder-of-file && chmod +x name-of-file` -- where the containing-folder-of-file is `/home/gabriel/Downloads/` and after that `chmod +x` where the `+x` is to make the file StarMade-Starter (1).jar executable. The filename of the StarMade-Starter (1).jar file is not important in this case. In case this is not clear enough, some executable files that were downloaded are already marked as executable and some executable files that were downloaded are not already marked as executable.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the .jar file. Select' Properties'. Then on the middle tab, tick the box that says Allow execution. Then double click the .jar file to execute it.